# Swift Multiple IF Statements

Tags: swift

I am trying to do have a 3 life feature in a quiz.

So I have added three buttons called:

```
btnLife1
btnLife2
btnLife3
```

My first two conditions work perfectly, the first two lives disappear in the quiz. However, when it comes to hiding the btnLife3 it doesn't hide in the sequence - I can't think why, is my syntax wrong or something?

Here is the code I am using:

```
//three lives start

            // if life 1 is visible
            // make life 1 hidden
            if (btnLife1?.hidden == false) {
                btnLife1!.hidden = true
            }
            // if life 1 is hidden
            // make life 2 hidden
            else if (btnLife1?.hidden == true) {
                btnLife2!.hidden = true
            }
            // if life 2 is hidden
            // make life 3 hidden
            else if (btnLife2?.hidden == true){
                btnLife3!.hidden = true
            }
            else if (btnLife3?.hidden == true) {
                //Game over
                DBFunction.insertData(self.playerName, score:String(format: "%d",self.playerScore))
                //{
                let scoreViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("scoreVC") as! ScoreviewController
                scoreViewController.playerScore = self.playerScore
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(scoreViewController, animated: true)
            }

            else {
                //
            }
            //three lives end
```

Comment: Debugging the code is likely to help you find out what's the problem.

Comment: "is my syntax wrong or something" --> your _syntax_ surely isn't the issue. if this was the case, the code wouldn't even compile (syntax errors are caught by the compiler). this is a _semantic_ issue in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a flaw in the logic.

Change your second condition to this:

```
        // if life 1 is hidden AND life 2 is NOT hidden
        // make life 2 hidden
        else if (btnLife1?.hidden == true && btnLife2?.hidden == false) {
            btnLife2!.hidden = true
        }
```

Bonus:

Do your variables HAVE to be optionals? You could simplify it this way:

```
let lives : [UIButton] = [btnLife1, btnLife2, btnLife3]

for life in lives {

    if !life.hidden {

        life.hidden = true
        return
    }
}
// Game Over if the control came through the for-loop without returning.
```

Comment: @Leo Dabus, no problem. Hence I suggested not declaring the buttons as optionals in my Bonus code.

Answer (score 1):

The second condition can't get chained onward. You need a new condition, try this:

```
 // if life 1 is hidden AND life 2 is NOT hidden
 // make life 2 hidden
 else if (btnLife1?.hidden == true) && (btnLife2?.hidden == false) {
   btnLife2?.hidden = true
 }
```

Comment: This code will fail because `Bool` properties of optionals might return a nil. He will still have to compare with true or false.